# Excel disconnects from clients on autofilter

Tags: vba, excel

In my Excel spreadsheet I have a table of data set up

I also have two buttons

One filters the fourth column to anything above 0

```
With ActiveSheet
       .Range("A138:H246").Select
       Selection.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">0", Operator:=xlAnd
End With
```

The other (is supposed to) remove the filter

```
With ActiveSheet
     .Range("A138:H246").Select
     Selection.AutoFilter Field:=4
End With
```

However, the button to remove the filter doesn't work, I keep receiving the following message

"The object invoked has disconnected from its clients autofilter"

I have tried recording a macro and then using that code but even that fails if i run the code on a button press

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok even by changing the code to 'Field:=4, Criteria1:="<999", Operator:=xlAnd' that fails on the same error code?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the below statement when you've finished with the filtered data.

Hope this helps?

```
Activesheet.AutoFilterMode = false
```

As you say this can give errors if autofilter is already false when you try and make it false, however if you position this line in your code at the right place the filter will always be true when you want to set it to false. as below

```
ActiveSheet.Range("someRange").AutoFilter Field:=27, Criteria1:="test"
' do something with filtered data
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```

This executes with no errors for me...

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, it crashes and shows an error message saying not enough memory?

Comment: As explain in my answer, this can easily generate errors regarding the current state of that mode in your sheet. (if it is already in the state you are trying to set, excel don't like that...)

Answer (score 0):

Mine says it should be as simple as this :

```
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

It just clear all filters, but it doesn't deactivate the AutoFilter mode, is it enough?

Here is the code to scan all used columns and store there hidden state before displaying all of them to use `ShowAllData` clear filters and rehide previously hidden columns.

```
Dim TH()
ReDim TH(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)

For j = LBound(TH) + 1 To UBound(TH)
    TH(j) = ActiveSheet.Columns(j).EntireColumn.Hidden
    ActiveSheet.Columns(j).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Next j

ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

For j = LBound(TH) + 1 To UBound(TH)
    ActiveSheet.Columns(j).EntireColumn.Hidden = TH(j)
Next j
```

If you need to change the AutoFilter mode :

```
Activesheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Activesheet.AutoFilterMode = True
```

But this can easily generate errors regarding the current state of that mode in your sheet. (if it is already in the state you are trying to set, excel don't like that...)

Comment: If I use ShowAllData I get the error message
"ShowAllData method of Worksheet class failed"

I need to keep other columns of the sheet hidden so i think this function is not a viable option

Comment: Ok, so I added a piece of code that could help you, let me know if it is enough